# Specifying redirect page to clicked link

Tags: python, http, browser, request, mechanize

I'm writing a script in python, using mechanize. I'm following a link:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.neopets.com/browseshop.phtml?owner=nick_291540") 
#returns last link
for link in br.links(url_regex="buy_item.phtml"):
    placeholder = 1

br.follow_link(link)
```

I want to pretend that I'm being directed to the link from a certain url. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Referer` header, example from [docs](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#adding-headers):

```
import mechanize
req = mechanize.Request("http://foobar.com/")
req.add_header("Referer", "http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/")
r = mechanize.urlopen(req)
```